# How to create a data frame with an array and a pandas data frame?

Tags: python

I have a numpy array and a pandas data frame which contains indexes. How can I join this two "elements" to create a data frame?
The "predicted_values" array and the "real_values" pandas data frame have 12600 elements. I want to create a data frame with 12600 rows and 2 columns (real and predicted values)

I have tried with concat and pandas data frame but I can't do it.
Thanks in advance !

```
predicted_values=array([3. , 2. , 7. , ..., 7. , 6. , 8.8])
```

The pandas data frame is like

```
index real_values

29400   3
29401   2
29402   7
29403   6
29404   6
...     ...
41994   4
41995   0
41996   1
41997   7
41998   6
41999   9
```

Comment: `df['predicted'] = predicted_values`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just perform simple assignment:

```
df['predicted_values'] = real_values
```

`pd.concat` works too:

```
pd.concat([df, pd.Series(a)], axis=1).rename(columns={0: 'predicted_values'})
```